# Convert a horizontal table to vertical table using python and pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie who just started out using python and I am looking for ways to convert the following table from excel.

FROM:

|  | 01-Jan-21 | 01-Jan-21 | 01-Jan-21 | 01-Jan-21 | 02-Jan-21 | 02-Jan-21 | 02-Jan-21 | 02-Jan-21 | 03-Jan-21 | 03-Jan-21 | 03-Jan-21 | 03-Jan-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Route | DO | DP | Case | Timing | DO | DP | Case | Timing | DO | DP | Case | Timing |
| E0 | 1 | 2 | 3.3 | 5:00PM | 2 | 3 | 36.3 | 3:00PM | 5 | 6 | 3.3 | 1:00PM |
| E1 | 1 | 2 | 6.1 | 4:00PM | 2 | 7 | 3.31 | 3:00AM | 5 | 9 | 33 | 5:00PM |

TO:

|  | DO | DP | Case | Timing | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E0 | 1 | 2 | 3.3 | 5:00PM | 01-Jan-21 |
| E1 | 1 | 2 | 6.1 | 4:00PM | 01-Jan-21 |
| E0 | 2 | 3 | 36.3 | 3:00PM | 02-Jan-21 |
| E1 | 2 | 7 | 3.31 | 3:00AM | 02-Jan-21 |
| E0 | 5 | 6 | 3.3 | 1:00PM | 03-Jan-21 |
| E1 | 5 | 9 | 33 | 5:00PM | 03-Jan-21 |

Any advise on how I should go about doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have 2 levels of header in your excel file. If you use `header=[0, 1]`, the rest will be easy:

```
# Create a MultiIndex
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0, 1], index_col=0)

# Rename axis
df = df.rename_axis(columns=['Date', None], index='Route')

# Pivot your dataframe
df = df.stack(level='Date').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Route       Date   Case  DO  DP  Timing
0    E0  01-Jan-21   3.30   1   2  5:00PM
1    E0  02-Jan-21  36.30   2   3  3:00PM
2    E0  03-Jan-21   3.30   5   6  1:00PM
3    E1  01-Jan-21   6.10   1   2  4:00PM
4    E1  02-Jan-21   3.31   2   7  3:00AM
5    E1  03-Jan-21  33.00   5   9  5:00PM
```